# How to combine dictionary of word-forms into a single list without duplicates

Tags: python

https://github.com/gutfeeling/word_forms

From the URL, I find out how to convert word into all the forms(verb, noun, adjective). I need that after conversion, list format.

e.g:

```
from word_forms.word_forms import get_word_forms

a=get_word_forms("review")
print(a)
```

output:

```
{'n': {'reviewer', 'reviewers', 'reviews', 'review'}, 'a': set(), 'v': {'reviewed', 'reviews', 'reviewing', 'review'}, 'r': set()}
```

my expected output is:

```
['reviewer', 'reviewers', 'reviews', 'review','reviewed', 'reviews', 'reviewing', 'review']
```

how this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all possible words (including the nouns, verbs, adjectives and so on) by using a *comprehension*. This loops over all elements of a sequence, as with a `for-loop`, but [can be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518899/comparing-list-comprehensions-and-explicit-loops-3-array-generators-faster-than/39518977).

In you case, you have a dictionary, so we loop over each **key-value** pair. The keys are **n** (noun), **a** (adjective), **v** (verb) and **r** (??). For each of these keys, we have a list of words, which we can append to your final desired output list, *if* they aren't already in the list.
Because we loop over a dictionary, and then over each of the lists, with becomes nested:

```
from word_forms.word_forms import get_word_forms
word_forms = get_word_forms("review")

desired_words = []
for word_type, word_list in word_forms.items():
    for word in word_list:
        if word not in desired_words:
            desired_words.append(word)

print(desired_words)
# ['reviewers', 'review', 'reviewer', 'reviews', 'reviewing', 'reviewed']
```

This can be compressed into a nested comprehension:

```
desired_words = []
{desired_words.append(word) for word_type, word_list in word_forms.items() for word in word_list if word not in desired_words}

print(desired_words)
# ['reviewers', 'review', 'reviewer', 'reviews', 'reviewing', 'reviewed']
```

We didn't need to save the resulting object, we only want to side-effect of appending to `desired_words`

Another way to do this would be to simply put all the words into a list, then convert it into a `set()` object, which would remove all duplicates and order the list alphabetically:

```
desired_words = []
# the 'if' statement is removed in the dictionary comprehension:
{desired.words.append(word) for word_type, word_list in word_forms.items() for word in word_list}
# Set removes duplicates - we then wrap it back into a list
desired_words = list(set(desired_words))
```

Answer (score 1):

For no duplicates:

```
list(set(b for c in a.values() for b in c))
```

If you don't want the elements to be unique:

```
[b for c in a.values() for b in c]
```

Comment: Why are you passing a list comprehension instead of a generator expression to `set()`?  Also if you are going to iterate over `c` why do you think converting it to a `list()` first is useful?

Comment: Well because I'm really new to python I guess? Good point.

Comment: I passed a list to set() since I was not sure what the poster really want. He asked for "without duplicates" in his title, but a simple list with duplicates in his content. So I went for the list first, and then forgot to drop the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
from word_forms.word_forms import get_word_forms

a=get_word_forms("review")

list_item=[];
list_item1=[];
list_item2=[];
list_item3=[];
for key,val in a.items():
    if(key=='n' ):
        for n in val:
            list_item.append(n)
    if (key == 'v'):
        for v in val:
            list_item1.append(v)
    if (key == 'r'):
        for r in val:
            list_item2.append(r)
    if (key == 'a'):
        for a in val:
            list_item3.append(a)


list=list_item+list_item1+list_item2+list_item3
print(list)
```

**output:**

```
['reviews', 'review', 'reviewers', 'reviewer', 'reviews', 'review', 'reviewing', 'reviewed']
```

Comment: In Python, `list` is a special word, which represent the actual `list` object. You should not call your variable `list`, because you would potentially cause problems when you overwrite built-in objects.